# Pass "e" to a new function - javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a function that waits for a click event on an img and then launches `imgclick();`.

This is all working as expected, but once inside the function I need to use `e.preventDefault()` which fails because "e" is not available. I thought I could remedy this by just passing in the literal `e`, but that was no good either. How should I access it properly? Below is my current JS...

```
var img = document.getElementsByClassName("img"),
    i;

function imgclick(id, e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}

for (i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
  img[i].addEventListener("click", imgclick(this.id, e));
}
```

I'm still getting the hang of not relying on jQuery, so sorry if this is a really obvious mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First :** when adding `eventListener`, you need **reference** to the `callback function`, not to *call it*.
 **Second :** `event`, or `e` *argument* should be the *first argument* of the `callback function`, there you can get `id` with `this.id`, or alternatively with `e.target.id`:

```
var img = document.getElementsByClassName("img"),
    i;

function imgclick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  var id=this.id;  //e.target.id     
 }

for (i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
  img[i].addEventListener("click", imgclick);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have already stated, `imgclick(this.id, e)` actually invokes your handler function instead of waiting until user clicks the `img`. For example, you can use enclosures and create a new handler for each of elements. Here is a jsfiddle based on your code: https://jsfiddle.net/crr5age4/

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide `addEventListener` with a function that takes a single argument (the event: `e`) and then pass that `event` on to your `imgclick` function.

If you can target only browsers that support ES2015 arrow functions you can just use:

```
img[i].addEventListener("click", e => imgclick(this.id, e));
```

Or for any ES5+ environment:

```
img[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) { imgclick(this.id, e) }.bind(this));
```

Or for any JavaScript environment:

```
var _this = this;
img[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) { imgclick(_this.id, e) });
```

If you don't need to access `this` you can get away with just

```
function(e) { imgclick(somethingElse.id, e) }
```

as the second argument instead.